# Missing component for Angular Material?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

All Angular Materials components seem to be included in the code and the "hello world" example itself is copied straight from the website.

But for some reason, when I try to load the file and test it there is no formatting whatsoever. What am I missing here?

```
<!doctype html>
<html  lang="en">
<head>
<title>
  Angular Material
</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=RobotoDraft:300,400,500,700,400italic">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">
</head>

<body>

<div layout="column" layout-fill>
  <md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <span>My App's Title</span>
      <!-- fill up the space between left and right area -->
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button>
        Right Bar Button
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-content>
    Hello!
  </md-content>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Controller and App reference to initialize Angular & the reference to "ngMaterial" to load the Angular Material module

```
var app = angular.module('StarterApp', ['ngMaterial']);

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', function($scope, $mdSidenav){
  $scope.toggleSidenav = function(menuId) {
    $mdSidenav(menuId).toggle();
  }; 
}]);
```

The JS references ng-app & ng-controller in your Markup:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="StarterApp">
..
<body layout="column" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
```

See http://codepen.io/marcysutton/pen/OPbpKm